# EntityFramework.6.1.2-beta1\tools\init.ps1 is restricted, cannot run enable-migrations Command

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, powershell, visual-studio-2013

**Visual Studio 2013 C# ASP.NET MVC problem EntityFramework.6.1.2-beta1\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded because its execution is blocked by software restriction policies. For more information, contact your system administrator.**

When I try to use the Enable-Migrations: I get the message below:
**The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spe
lling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Enable-Migrations <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

I have the above Issue, and I tried all sorts of solutions for it, but none of them helped

Things that I have already done:

1. removed all nuget extention and installed it Again  *(Didn't Work)*
2. Removed Entity Framework and reinstalled it again  *(Didn't Work)*
3. closed my visual studio 2013 and reopened the file  *(Didn't Work)*
4. Opened visual studio using Administrator  *(Didn't Work)*
5. Deleted the whole package brought package from a different project  *(Didn't Work)*

I even tried some power shell commands, still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
The reason was that, my user-profile was somehow blocking me from running the init.ps1 file of EntityFramework.
I created a new user profile, with admin rights, and Ran Visual Studio on that profile, and  now the EntityFramework, works perfectly.
Incase if you have the same problem, try the above, stuff that I have already tried, and if none of them work, then try this..

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to set the executions policies locally.

To do this, enter this command in the PS first:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

See this link for more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I ran this command in the Package Manager Console and was able to execute commands like Update-Database immediately.

Comment: No prob, please note that this command will change some security aspects of the PS-shell. I updated the answer with a link.

Comment: I want to mention that in Visual Studio 2013 the EF init script has ran without issue for a long time. Setting execution policy was only needed when I moved to Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Remove file inside

control=>internet option => content => certificates =>Untrusted publishers

then problem will gone in my case

Comment: is it safe for non localhost environments?