# package manager console error - visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I keep getting the same error when I'm trying to load project in .net. The error is:

> packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.

i tried to do Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned or Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
on power shell but still not working 
this problem wont allow me to use migration,update-database etc.

Comment: Have you tried to launch Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: yes and it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried suggested approaches from the accepted answers from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26355475/3095779) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19101637/3095779)?

Comment: the second one i tried. but how do i open new user profile on visual studio?

Comment: Please try then first approach to find out if it may help you.

Comment: but how do i open new user profile on visual studio?

Comment: It's not about Visual Studio User Profile, it's about just a regular Windows User Profile.

Comment: well it still doesnt work...

Comment: see the workaround I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433786/8358565